# How to use exit status in crontab

Tags: shell-script, rhel, cron

I add the following script line to the red-hat crontab, script should run on Saturday in 5:00 in the morning. In order to run the script `/var/scripts/PLW.pl` every Saturday at 05:00 morning. I want to check the exit status from the script.

my question : is it possible to add in the crontab after the script line the something like this

```
0 0 * * 5   /var/scripts/PLW.pl 
[[ $? -eq 0 ]] && run_once.bash
```

so if exit status is 0 the `run_once.bash` script will be activated.

Comment: just put `/var/scripts/PLW.pl  && run_once.bash` on one line. `&&` means do the following command if the previous command exit code is true, ie 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
0 0 * * 5  /usr/bin/python /var/scripts/PLW.pl && /bin/bash /path/to/run_once.bash
```

Note : `&& /bin/bash /path/to/run_once.bash` will only run if previous command run successfully. So instead of using exit code, you can use `&&`'s inbuilt functionality.

Comment: The `if` test is superfluous because the `&&` means it will only be done if the exit code is 0.

Comment: @meuh Oh yeah, I don't know how I didn't realized it.

Comment: Also, you can't use backslashes to continue a line inside of crontab (as you did in the first version of this answer).

Comment: @Wildcard I used '\' just for the sake of clearity. One line was looking bit messy and hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

use   `0 0 * * 5   /var/scripts/PLW.pl`
run 'run_once.sh' from your perl program with `system("/bin/sh","/path/run_once.sh");` before `exit($EXIT_SUCCESS);` 
A cluttered crontab is bad, comment your perl program instead.

Edit: or just use `exec()` from perl.